# Does my cat have ringworm?

Tags: cats, diseases

Tobby is a playful cat, and while he was trying to reach his ball under the bed he got some scratches on his forehead. This happened around 2 weeks ago, and shortly after I noticed few rashes around both his ears, and few days ago I started treating it with miconazole cream. I have clipped the hair in that particular region. Can someone please give their opinions whether this is ringworm or something else?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vet confirmed that this is ringworm merely by visual assessment, and asked me to continue it treating with the miconazole cream. Nonetheless I decided myself to start treating him also with Terbinafine pills, and give it a few weeks to see if there is any improvement.